# What is the meaning of providing source type with Security group on security group role in SoftLayer?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I see that that it can have two values: either security group which is termed as remoteGroupId in the API http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_SecurityGroup_Rule

and remoteIp which is CIDR. How does remoteGroupId work as source type?

Answer (score 0):

It is the id of the security group associated to the rule, you can see the documentation here http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_SecurityGroup

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it just means that particular rule is applicable to all the VSI which are the assigned to security group whose id is remoteGroupId.

Answer (score 0):

When I were creating a firewall rule, there's a field for *SourceType* and I can select another security group instead of CIDR Block.

So I wonder what will happen on firewall side when I selected another security group?

I assume that it will inherit that group but in functionality it didn't work that.

Here's my case:

```
Security Group A: Has 4 IP address as inbound rule allow all.
Security Group B: Allow only 22 port as inbound with source type: Security Group A

Security Group A didn't assigned to any instance.
Security Group B assigned to VSI (VM with CentOS) public instance.
```

I expect that 4 IP address that in security group has an access to only 22 port on my VM but in reality 22 port didn't accept any connection from those addresses.

If I change Security Group B rule, duplicate 22 port rule and change source type as CIDR and put IP address and make this same action for all desired IPs it works fine but this not the solution that I want because in this case I have to define all IPs for all expected ports (If I have 20 IP, and 10 different port than I have to define 200 rules which is not logic)